# NestJS - Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, http-status

In my NestJs project, I am using decorator `@Res() res` and using the response object to set custom response header status by multiple cases.
When calling, sometimes it logs:  `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client`

After I viewed the issues list in Github and searching on the internet, I know this is relating to Express middleware and the built-in filter of NestJs.

So, I remove `.send()` and add  `return;` at the end of the Controller method, the log will disappear.

My first code:

```
@Get()
get(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
  const result = this.service.getData(req);
  res.status(result.statusCode).json(result.data).send(); // when using .send(), it will cause error
}
```

Code after I fixed look like this:

```
@Get()
get(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
  const result = this.service.getData(req);
  res.status(result.statusCode).json(result.data); // when remove .send(), it will succeed
  return;
}
```

My question: Do I have to add  `return;` at the end of the method? Why using `.send()` **sometimes**  cause error but not **always**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

because `requet.json({...})` already send response to "client". So `.send()` after `requet.json({...})` will try to send another response.

the good way to do is to return response like this:

```
return res.status(result.statusCode).json(result.data);
```

because if you miss `return` your code may cause unexpected result.

Example:

```
res.status(result.statusCode).json(result.data); //response is sent
let a = "Something good"; // Code will be executed
console.log(a); // Code will be executed
```