# NestJS/Express Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: express, nestjs

Sometimes my server (**NestJS**) crashed with the following stack:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at ExpressAdapter.reply (/home/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:24:57)
    at ExceptionsHandler.handleUnknownError (/home/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/base-exception-filter.js:33:24)
    at ExceptionsHandler.catch (/home/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/base-exception-filter.js:17:25)
    at ExceptionsHandler.next (/home/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:16:20)
    at /home/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:24:35
    at Layer.handle_error (/home/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /home/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (/home/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

I tried to fix it with few advices I saw on similar SO (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074405/nestjs-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)) but it still happens.

Dependencies used:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^7.6.12",
"@nestjs/config": "^0.6.3",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.6.12",
"@nestjs/jwt": "^7.2.0",
"@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.2.3",
"@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.5",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.12",
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^7.6.12",
"@nestjs/platform-ws": "^7.6.12",
"@nestjs/schedule": "^0.4.3",
"@nestjs/websockets": "^7.6.12",
"@types/string-similarity": "^4.0.0",
"bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
"class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
"class-validator": "^0.11.1",
"dotenv": "^10.0.0",
"express-useragent": "^1.0.15",
"mongodb": "^3.5.5",
"mongoose": "^5.9.7",
"nanoid": "^3.1.12",
"nestjs-i18n": "^8.1.0",
"nestjs-stripe": "^0.4.1",
"nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
"passport": "^0.4.1",
"passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rimraf": "^3.0.0",
"rxjs": "^6.5.3",
"string-similarity": "^4.0.4",
"stripe": "^8.39.0",
"typeorm": "^0.2.24"
```

The code that may be problematic:

**AppController**:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {

    @Get()
    root(@Res() response): void {
        return response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname+'/../gui/index.html'));
    }

}
```

**AppMiddleware**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

    use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
        const url = req.originalUrl;
        if (url.indexOf('api') === 1) {
            // it starts with /api --> continue with execution
            return next();
        } else if (allowedExt.filter(ext => url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
            // it has a file extension --> resolve the file
            return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + `/../gui/${url}`), err => {
                // Error: redirect to index.html
                if (err) {
                    return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../gui/index.html'));
                }
            });
        } else {
            // in all other cases, redirect to the index.html
            return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../gui/index.html'));
        }
    }

}
```

I also tried with no return:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

    use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
        const url = req.originalUrl;
        if (url.indexOf('api') === 1) {
            // it starts with /api --> continue with execution
            next();
        } else if (allowedExt.filter(ext => url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
            // it has a file extension --> resolve the file
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + `/../gui/${url}`), err => {
                // Error: redirect to index.html
                if (err) {
                    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../gui/index.html'));
                }
            });
        } else {
            // in all other cases, redirect to the index.html
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../gui/index.html'));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppMiddleware`:

```js
return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + `/../gui/${url}`), err => {
    // Error: redirect to index.html
    if (err) {
        return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../gui/index.html'));
    }
});
```

This might be the cause. Your `response` ended after `sendFile` even when there would be an error, so you shouldn't invoke it in the callback.

Comment: I already tried with no `retun` (see my edit), what do you suggest?

Comment: @Emeric after calling `sendFile`, you can't invoke any response's function because it's the end of request - response cycle. That why invoking `sendFile` again in the callback leads to this error.